# Бесконечная загрузка storybook для react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Я столкнулся с бесконечной загрузкой в веб интерфейсе. Компоненты не отображаются, ошибок и предупреждений нет. Не могли бы посоветовать способ исправить это или локализовать причину?

Шаги для воспроизведения:

1. npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react_native
2. add export {default} from "./storybook" to index.js
3. npx react-native start
4. npx react-native run-android
5. npm run storybook
6. бесконечная загрузка в веб интерфейсе

Параметры компьютера:

1. OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
2. CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz

ПО:

1. Node: 12.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/bin/node
2. npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.1/bin/npm

Браузеры:

1. Chrome: 86.0.4240.193
2. Firefox: 83.0

Версия storybook:

@storybook/cli: 6.1.1

Comment: Это StackOverflow __на русском__, пожалуйста переведи вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.